# Activity has leaked window PopupWindow after rotation

Tags: java, android

When I rotate my device while showing a `PopupMenu`, I get a `WindowLeaked` error.

That's my `PopupMenu`:

```
private void showSelectionMenu(View caller) {
    popup = new PopupMenu(this, caller);
//  popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.selection_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.inflate(R.menu.selection_menu);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(FileListActivity.this, getString(R.string.selecting)+" "+item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.select_all:                   mediaFolder.selectAll(); break;
                case R.id.select_none:                  mediaFolder.selectNone(); break;
                case R.id.select_videos:                mediaFolder.selectVideos(); break;
                case R.id.select_pictures:              mediaFolder.selectImages(); break;
                default:                                break;
            }
            findViewById(R.id.buttonRenameSelected).setEnabled(mediaFolder.numberSelected>0);
            cla.redraw();
            return true;
        }
    });
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu) {
                Log.d(TAG, "selectionMenu dismissed");
            }
        });
    }
    popup.show();
}
```

I know that many programmers here had the same error before and usually they are told to dismiss the menu in `onDestroy()`. So do I:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "FileListActivity onDestroy()");
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: popup==null? "+(popup==null));
    if (popup != null) { popup.dismiss(); popup = null; }
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: popup==null? "+(popup==null));

    dataFragment.mRetainedCache = mMemoryCache;
    dataFragment.setData(mediaFolder);
}
```

And that's the resulting log including the error:

```
02-10 22:24:15.969 D: FileListActivity onDestroy()
02-10 22:24:15.969 D: onDestroy: popup==null? false
02-10 22:24:15.971 D: selectionMenu dismissed
02-10 22:24:15.971 D: onDestroy: popup==null? true
02-10 22:24:16.064 E: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myApp.FileListActivity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{365b288 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-822,1152} that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1378)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1234)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(AppCompatPopupWindow.java:78)
    at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompatKitKat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompatKitKat.java:30)
    at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat$KitKatPopupWindowImpl.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:92)
    at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:171)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:680)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:163)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:129)
    at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:216)
    at com.myApp.FileListActivity.showSelectionMenu(FileListActivity.java:434)
    at com.myApp.FileListActivity.access$100(FileListActivity.java:44)
    at com.myApp.FileListActivity$5.onClick(FileListActivity.java:186)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
02-10 22:24:16.079 D: FileListActivity onCreate()
```

As you can see in the log, the `PopupMenu` (`popup`) is dismissed and set to `null` before the error occurs.

Any idea what's going wrong?

EDIT:

That's where `showSelectionMenu(View caller)` is called (in `onCreate`):

```
Button buttonSelectFiles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectFiles);
buttonSelectFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showSelectionMenu(v);
    }
});
```

EDIT 2:

I just found out that I get that error on my Nexus 5 running Android 7.1.1 (LineageOS, nightly build) but not on a Fire HD 8 running Fire OS 5.3.2.1 (based on Android 5) and not either on a Samsung Galaxy S+ running Android 4.4.4 (CyanogenMod 11). So maybe it only happens on Android 7 or maybe there is a bug in LineageOS!?
If anybody has an official Android 7, he/she could try to provoke that error using this [Android Popup Menu Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example). You only would have to add this code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (popup != null) { popup.dismiss(); popup = null; }
}
```

and make `popup` a class member variable.

EDIT 3:

It's not a LineageOS problem. This error also occurs in the Android Studio Emulator running Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Yes, it's the same behavior. And also the same when dismissing in  onPause().

Answer (score 0):

Error is occured when your code tries to show popup. Activities are recreated after rotation change so I think your `caller` parameter contains a View from the activity destroyed. You should check where `caller` parameter comes from and reassign if necessary.

Comment: The caller is a button. It's defined in the onCreate method. That's correct, isn't it? I have added some more code to my question.

Comment: It looks correct. You can disable recreation via manifest. Add this `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to your activity.

Comment: Thanks, I know. But it's not recommended: "This technique should be considered a last resort". I would rather like to understand what's wrong with my code.